# Any Open source Ada(latest, 2012) IDE?

Tags: ide, ada

I am trying to use Ada for Automotive programming to take advantages of Safety critical abilities of the language. I only saw commercial licenses for the development tools from (Libre, GNAT programming studio).

Are there any free Ada IDE's?

Comment: You mention "Open source" and "free" in the same post, and I suspect the latter is "free as in free beer". You need to clarify the language here. Obviously, if you want to do safety critical code, you'll have at some point to rely on qualified tools, and these tools are expensive to develop and maintain.

Comment: If the emphasis is on "trying", then GNAT Programming Studio is available for free, too, as are Eclipse based IDEs (AdaCore, PTC), and maybe others for evaluation.

Answer (score 9):

GPS and Emacs (ada-mode) are both licensed under the GPL, but that doesn’t matter because you won’t be delivering them to your users. They are both *environments* that enable *you* to *run a compiler and associated tools*.

If you need to deliver *your* software certified by an independent authority, you’ll likely be paying them a lot more than any support contract you got from AdaCore, and they'll likely want you to have more tool support than you get with AdaCore’s GPL toolset.

But if you don’t have certification or support issues, then you can use GPS or Emacs with a compiler of your choice:

- if you’re able to release your software under the GPL, you can use AdaCore’s GNAT GPL compiler;
- if not, you can use an FSF GCC Ada compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the options are GNAT GPS and Emacs.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest solution to the requirement described by you seems to be located here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ideada/

I am not sure of the version of ADA supported by the app though.